# 2 byte difference for the same salt and key combination using openssl SHA512

Tags: openssl

I am finding a 2 byte difference between hashes generated by the same salt and string combination at different times. the library being used is openssl. the code is

```
unsigned char digest[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
 SHA512((unsigned char*)(input.c_str()), input.size(), (unsigned char*)&digest);
```

The generated hashes in base64 form are as below 
watBYt80/mWSXEap3+snTJt9LpvCb/fJl1f7yF2KTYEnFG9m0APT+GxvaNbAd9UhvGwZRnhhXC+ml7YCHkGFFXDqJAE= 
watBYt80/mWSXEap3+snTJt9LpvCb/fJl1f7yF2KTYEnFG9m0APT+GxvaNbAd9UhvGwZRnhhXC+ml7YCHkGFFXDKeAE=

please notice the last 5 characters of which the first 2 differ. 
surprisingly the number of characters that differ changes basing on the length of the key. the length of the salt is always constant.

Comment: Did you mean to say `input.size()`? `size()` is a member function of `std::string`, not a member variable.

Comment: oh my bad yes ofcourse. will correct it.